# Shrunk CSS background on the iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

Why does body tag's background on this site [link](http://www.youreasttexasrealestate.com/) appears shrunk on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Safari has the tendency to scale large background images. To avoid that you can set the background size: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: Setting the background-size to the exact dimensions of the background image solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely create a separate stylesheet for the iPad. You can use the following to do so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="../ipad.css" type="text/css" />
```

On this link, you will find information about the orientation of your website on the iPad and how to deal with it.

My advice would be, to create a separate stylesheet (css file) for the iPad version of your site, no matter what you do, you should just create it and add a link tag like the one shown above.

If you have a large background picture for the iPad version, you can reduce it to fit the iPad, if that's the only thing you've got a problem with. I'd say you should reduce the size of the image to 1024px and declare it in the separate stylesheet for the iPad, and you will see the end result.

BTW you should read this article as well: http://www.inspiredm.com/2010/02/09/ipad-design/